# Incorrect value for totalEstimatedMatches in Azure Bing Custom Search

Tags: azure, count, bing, azure-cognitive-services, bing-search

We are trying to search results from a particular website using Azure Cognitive Bing Custom Search APIs for specified keywords. We have a business requirement to show the total number of search results on the search page when user search for a keyword. However, the **totalEstimatedMatches** returns an incorrect value.

We are using **offset and count** parameters to navigate the results. When we reach to the nearby offset, it gives us the correct value for totalEstimatedMatches.
How can we get the correct value for totalEstimatedMatches with the first search result, so that we can display the value of total records on the search page of our application?

[image]